# Помогите написать калькулятор на JS

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Помогите пожалуйста написать функцию, которая выполняет арифметические операции двух чисел в виде строки и возвращает строку с результатом.

вот требования:

1.Калькулятор умеет выполнять операции сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления с двумя числами: a + b, a - b, a * b, a / b. Данные передаются в виде одной строки!

2.Калькулятор умеет работать как с арабскими (1,2,3,4,5…), так и с римскими (I,II,III,IV,V…) числами. Оба операнда должны быть либо арабскими, либо римскими.

3.Операнды должны лежать в диапазоне от 1 до 10 включительно, без ноля. Ответ может быть больше 10.

4.Калькулятор умеет работать только с целыми числами, принимает и возвращает.

5.Результат на выходе всегда строка с целым числом. В делении учитываем только целую часть - десятичную отбрасываем, например 2 / 4 = 0,5 - вернём 0.

6.Калькулятор умеет работать только с арабскими или римскими цифрами одновременно, при вводе пользователем строки вроде 3 + II калькулятор должен выбросить исключение (ошибку) и прекратить свою работу.

7.Поскольку в римской системе счисления нет нуля и отрицательных чисел, то вместо них возвращаем пустую строку. (например I - II = ‘’)

8.При вызове калькулятора с неподходящими числами, функция выбрасывает исключение и завершает свою работу.

9.При вызове калькулятора со строкой, которая не является математическим примером с одной из арифметических операций, описанных в требовании, приложение выбрасывает исключение и завершает свою работу.

и вот что я сделала, а дальше ступор. не пойму :(

```
function calculator(string) {

  const [num1, operator, num2] = string.split(' ');

  const a = Number(num1); // преобразовываем в число

  const b = Number(num2);


// Вычисляем результат в зависимости от оператора

  let result;

  switch (operator) {

    case '+':
      result = a + b;
      break;

    case '-':
      result = a - b;
      break;

    case '*':
      result = a * b;
      break;

    case '/':
      if (b === 0) {
        throw new Error('Division by zero');
      }

      result = a / b;
      break;

    default:
      throw new Error('Invalid operator');
  
  }

  // Возвращаем результат в виде строки

  return String(result);

}
```

Дальше мне видимо нужно обозначить как то римские цифры, затем перевести их в арабские, а дальше что?

Comment: Дальше вам надо создать справочник римских цифр для перевода их к арабским и обратно. Ну и пошагово идти и реализовывать требования. Я бы начал с последних, т.к. вначале надо определить, что пришло, а уже потом выполнять вычисления

Answer (score 2):

Вам понадобится справочник для римских чисел(т.к. по условию их всего 9)

```
const rimValues = {
  I: 1,
  II: 2,
  III: 3,
  IV: 4,
  V: 5,
  VI: 6,
  VII: 7,
  VIII: 8,
  IX: 9,
  X: 10,
}
```

Далее создадим справочник операций, которые умеет делать калькулятор

```
const calcActions = {
  '+': '+',
  '-': '-',
  '*': '*',
  '/': '/',
}
```

Создадим функцию, которая будет проверять переданные числа и оператор на корректность

```
function checkValues(val, index) {
  if (index === 1) { // Проверка оператора
    return [calcActions[val] ?? false, 'O'];
  } else { // Проверка числа
    const rim = rimValues[val];
    if (rim) return [rim, 'R']; // Если римские цифры
    const arab = Number(val);
    if (!isNaN(arab) && arab > 0 && arab <= 10) {
      return [arab, 'A'];
    }
    return [false, 'E'];
  }
}
```

Для преобразования ответа к римским цифрам, понадобится функция конвертор(функцию взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083037/convert-a-number-into-a-roman-numeral-in-javascript/9083076#9083076) и модифицировал под задачу)

```
function romanize (num) {
  if (num < 1) return ''; // Если меньше 1, то возвращаем пустую строку
  const digits = num.toString().split("");
  const key = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM",
    "","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC",
    "","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"];
  let roman = ""
  let i = 3;
  while (i--) roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman;
  
  return roman;
}
```

Так же потребуется функция преобразования полученного результата вычислений

```
function transformAnswer(res, arab) {
  return `Результат: ${arab ? Math.floor(res).toString() : romanize(Math.floor(res))}`;
}
```

В самой функции расставляем проверки на корректность данных с преобразованием римских цифр в арабские

```
function calculator(calcString) {
  if (typeof calcString !== 'string') throw new Error('NOT String'); // Не строка
  
  let calcValues = calcString.trim().split(' ');
  // Теперь надо понять, все ли значения правильные
  if (calcValues.length !== 3) throw new Error('Неправильная строка');
  let noError = true; // флаг наличия ошибок
  const arabRim = []; // числа арабские или римские переданы
  const errorIndex = []; // Записываем полученные ошибки
  calcValues = calcValues.map((item, index) => {
    const [res, v] = checkValues(item, index); // проверяем значение
    if (res) { // Значение есть
      if (v !== 'O') arabRim.push(v); // если не оператор, пишем тип числа
    } else { // Ошибка с данными
      noError = false; // взводим флаг
      errorIndex.push(`${item} ${v === 'E' ? 'Ошибка преобразования' : v === 'O' ? 'Неправильный оператор' : 'Ошибка диапазона'}`)
    }
    return res
  });
  if (!noError) { // Если есть ошибки, останавливаемся
    throw new Error(errorIndex.join('; '))
  }
  if (arabRim[0] !== arabRim[1]) { // Если разные системы счисления, останавливаемся
    throw new Error('Разные системы счисления')
  }
  // Проверки пройдены, считаем и возвращаем результат
  switch (calcValues[1]) {
    case '+':
      return transformAnswer(calcValues[0] + calcValues[2], arabRim[0] === 'A');
    case '-':
      return transformAnswer(calcValues[0] - calcValues[2], arabRim[0] === 'A');
    case '*':
      return transformAnswer(calcValues[0] * calcValues[2], arabRim[0] === 'A');
    case '/':
      return transformAnswer(calcValues[0] / calcValues[2], arabRim[0] === 'A');
    default:
      throw new Error('Неизвестный математический оператор')
  }
}
```

Полный рабочий пример кода с JSDoc аннотацией ниже:

```js
const rimValues = {
  I: 1,
  II: 2,
  III: 3,
  IV: 4,
  V: 5,
  VI: 6,
  VII: 7,
  VIII: 8,
  IX: 9,
  X: 10,
}

const calcActions = {
  '+': '+',
  '-': '-',
  '*': '*',
  '/': '/',
}

/**
 * @param {string} val
 * @param {number} index
 * @return {[string | number | boolean, string]}
 */
function checkValues(val, index) {
  if (index === 1) {
    return [calcActions[val] ?? false, 'O'];
  } else {
    const rim = rimValues[val];
    if (rim) return [rim, 'R'];
    const arab = Number(val);
    if (!isNaN(arab) && arab > 0 && arab <= 10) {
      return [arab, 'A'];
    }
    return [false, 'E'];
  }
}

/**
 * @param {number} num
 * @return {string}
 */
function romanize(num) {
  if (num < 1) return '';
  const digits = num.toString().split('');
  const key = ["", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM",
    "", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC",
    "", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"
  ];
  let roman = '';
  let i = 3;
  while (i--) roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman;
  return roman;
}

/**
 * @param {number} res
 * @param {boolean} arab
 * @return {string}
 */
function transformAnswer(res, arab) {
  return `Результат: ${arab ? Math.floor(res).toString() : romanize(Math.floor(res))}`;
}

/**
 * @param {string} calcString
 * @return {string}
 */
function calculator(calcString) {
  if (typeof calcString !== 'string') throw new Error('NOT String');
  /** @type {string[]} */
  let calcValues = calcString.trim().split(' ');
  // Теперь надо понять, все ли значения правильные
  if (calcValues.length !== 3) throw new Error('Неправильная строка');
  let noError = true;
  const arabRim = [];
  const errorIndex = [];
  calcValues = calcValues.map((item, index) => {
    const [res, v] = checkValues(item, index);
    if (res) {
      if (v !== 'O') arabRim.push(v);
    } else {
      noError = false;
      errorIndex.push(`${item} ${v === 'E' ? 'Ошибка преобразования' : v === 'O' ? 'Неправильный оператор' : 'Ошибка диапазона'}`)
    }
    return res
  });
  if (!noError) {
    throw new Error(errorIndex.join('; '))
  }
  if (arabRim[0] !== arabRim[1]) {
    throw new Error('Разные системы счисления')
  }

  switch (calcValues[1]) {
    case '+':
      return transformAnswer(calcValues[0] + calcValues[2], arabRim[0] === 'A');
    case '-':
      return transformAnswer(calcValues[0] - calcValues[2], arabRim[0] === 'A');
    case '*':
      return transformAnswer(calcValues[0] * calcValues[2], arabRim[0] === 'A');
    case '/':
      return transformAnswer(calcValues[0] / calcValues[2], arabRim[0] === 'A');
    default:
      throw new Error('Неизвестный математический оператор')
  }
}

/*****************************
 ТЕСТИРУЕМ
*****************************/

const variantsGood = ['1 + 2', 'II * VII', '10 / 2', '8 - 5', 'III - III', 'III - V'];
const variantsBad = ['2313', '2 +4 ', '2 + 3 + 5', '11 + 1', '1 + I', 'XX + V', '6 : 3', 'e + 2', 123, {},
  ['1 + 2'], ''
];

variantsGood.forEach(item => {
  try {
    console.log(item, calculator(item));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(item, e)
  }
})

variantsBad.forEach(item => {
  try {
    console.log(item, calculator(item));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(item, e.message)
  }
})
```